# Trying to write new properties to a file without a new line for each one

Tags: ant

I am using the ant PropertyFile task in this fashion with the goal of writing out properties to a file:

```
<propertyfile file="${file}">
  <entry key="${candidate.property}" value="${candidate.value}"/>
</propertyfile>
```

The problem is that it writes out successive properties with line breaks between them.

There are no line breaks in candidate value. The problem is that line breaks appear between the properties, like so:

```
first.prop=a

second.prop=b

third.prop=c
```

I expect there is no way around this in ant, please correct me if I'm wrong.
Is there a standard approach to this problem?

My default guess is that I should just define my own ant task in java that does this.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your comment.Are you saying that `${candidate.value}` contains line breaks, and you want to eliminate them in `${candidate.value}`? Or, is the problem that the property file itself has line breaks between the properties?

Comment: No, its line breaks between the properties. I've edited the Q to make this clearer. Is it surprising that line breaks appear between the properties?

Comment: Is there a problem with the blank lines?   This appears to be working as designed.  Check the Javadoc for Properties.load(Reader) method and it explains how the lines/data is handled.   The <loadproperties> task can read the file created by your example too - so don't think that should be a problem.

Comment: Yes I know it is working as designed and can be read in without any problems. My objective though is to get rid of the blank lines. I don't want to get too much into application specific detail here but basically the property file in question has several scripts writing to it in a similar way. It will help it to be more structured and maintainable if it is not formatted with line breaks. Is there a standard way of avoiding these? (I actually don't understand what the purpose of having them is anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I've spent several hours today trying to do exactly what you want to do.  Here's how I solved the problem in my properties file.

```
<target name="set-property" depends="apply-existing-value">
    <property name="value.to.write" value="${value}"/>
        <echo file="${file}" append="true">${name}=${value}${line.separator}</echo>
</target>
```

Forget propertyfile and use echo instead.  Substitute your key and value where I have ${name} and ${value}.  The ${line.separator} puts the next property on a new line NO EXTRA LINE FEED!